# cannot return zero value in matlab

Tags: c, matlab, return-value

I am new to matlab. I want to return 0, if the value of `e` is `NaN`. Following is my code:

```
      if(e!='NaN')
        fprintf(1,'The final coefficiant is: %f \n',e);
          else
            return 0;
       end
```

It's showing me

> Unexpected MATLAB operator.

Can anybody tell me why? How should I write it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also != is not a valid MATLAB operator. That's your error.
 Use `~=`

Nothing is ever, ever, ever == NaN.

Not even NaN.  Use `isnan`

```
function out = my_fun(e)      
if ~isnan(e)
    fprintf('The final coefficiant is: %f \n',e);
    out = 1; % or whatever
else
    out = 0;
end
```

Comment: Still error `Error using isnan
Not enough input arguments.

Error in mytest (line 173)
       if(e~=isnan),`

Comment: The proper syntax is `if ~isnan(e)`, not `if(e~=isnan)`

Answer (score 1):

Matlab functions do not return a value in the same way as regular functions.  Look at this example:

```
function success = myfunc()
e = rand(); % Compute e in some way
  if ~isnan(e)
    fprintf(1,'The final coefficiant is: %f \n',e);
    success = true;
  else         
    success = false;
  end
```

The `return` keyword will exit the function, but it is *not* intended for passing return values.  You can use `isnan` to check for NaN.

Comment: It is not taking this comparison of e with `NaN`

Comment: Please explain more.  I don't understand.

Comment: It's showing `Unexpected MATLAB operator.` in the `if` comparison line

Comment: gothcha.  I didn't notice that you were trying to compare with NaN.  Use the `isnan` function for this.